# C# visual studio 2015 submitting form data to a database that I created

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2015

[I think I have a database added.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIlvk.png)So I have this form created where the user choose from the 4 different seasons and 7 divisions. They can enter their own team name. I have a database connected (I'm pretty sure) but I want to submit this form data to the database upon button click. I have looked rather extensively, and will continue to do so in the mean time, but haven't been able to find something specific to my situation.

Here is my code for the form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace KickballSTL
{
    public partial class addTeam : Form
    {
        public addTeam()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            seasonComboBox.Items.Add("Winter");
            seasonComboBox.Items.Add("Spring");
            seasonComboBox.Items.Add("Summer");
            seasonComboBox.Items.Add("Fall");

            divisionComboBox.Items.Add("Saint Charles");
            divisionComboBox.Items.Add("South County Sundays");
            divisionComboBox.Items.Add("South County Thursdays");
            divisionComboBox.Items.Add("South City");
            divisionComboBox.Items.Add("Wentzville");
            divisionComboBox.Items.Add("Valley Park");
            divisionComboBox.Items.Add("Swansea, Illinois");

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                string teamDivision;
                string Season;
                string teamName;


                teamDivision = divisionComboBox.Text;
                teamName = teamNameTextBox.Text;
                Season = seasonComboBox.Text;


                // exception handler for empty fields    
                if (Season == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter your season!");
                }
                else if (teamDivision == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter your division!");
                }
                else if (teamName == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter your team name!");
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The following has been added to the database:"+ "Season: " + seasonComboBox.Text + "\r\n" + "Division: " + 
                        divisionComboBox.Text + "\r\n" +   "Team Name: " + teamNameTextBox.Text + );
                }

            }

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Thanks for any and all help, and I do appreciate your assistance.

Derek

Comment: Are you using entity framework ?    Put your controller and view here...it will be better to help you

Comment: Hey Derek, it's unclear *what* you have looked for extensively. You would know whether or not you have a database connected, because you'd have written the code that connects it. I would suggest revising your question (or replying in comments) on what exactly you have tried and what you need help on.

Comment: So I right clicked on the program in solution explorer and add an item --> database. That's how I added a database, I never had to write any code however.